# Total stress and total strain in thermoelasticity

Tags: temperature, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

For a solid undergoing thermoelastic deformation, we can write the total stress as

$$
\sigma_{total} = \sigma_{mechanical} - \sigma_{thermal}
$$
Where
$$
\sigma_{mechanical} = C:\epsilon_{mechanical} \\
\sigma_{thermal} = C:\epsilon_{thermal}
$$
Where
$$
\epsilon_{mechanical} = 0.5[\nabla u + (\nabla u)^T]\\
\epsilon_{thermal} = \alpha \Delta T
$$
where $\alpha$ is the coefficient of thermal expansion.

However, the total strain is frequently written as
$$
\epsilon_{total} = \epsilon_{mech} + \epsilon_{thermal}
$$
So it is the sum of the mechanical and thermal strains, whereas the total stress is the mechanical stress MINUS the thermal stress.

I am confused as to why the strain is the summation of the 2 strain contributors, but stress is the difference between the 2 stress contributors. Could someone explain or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I think this is a question of sign convention, perhaps coming from different texts.

Comment: @JonCuster I thought so at first too, but I don't think it is a sign convention thing.

Comment: From an engineering point of view the "minus" logic makes no sense, because $e_{\text{mech}}$ should be the only part of the strain that generates stress.  "Thermal stress" is the same sort of fictitious quantity as "centrifugal force". A body doesn't have internal stress because of thermal expansion, it has stress because of thermal expansion *plus some constraints on the way it deforms*.

Comment: … in other words, there is only *one* stress contributor, and that comes from the mechanical strain. which would be better called *elastic strain* not mechanical strain. Working this way is even more important if the material behaviour is nonlinear (e.g. plasticity) - there is then plastic strain as well as thermal strain and elastic strain, but no "plastic stress" or "thermal stress".

Answer (score 0):

Strain is usually considered positive if the solid expands and negative otherwise. Then, it is reasonable to consider the total strain equal to the sum of all strains (elastic, plastic, thermal, creep, etc.). Thermal strain will only produce stresses if a restraint exists that impedes fully or partially the displacement of the body cause by a temperature change. However, that means that when the body tries to expand (positive strain), a restraint will prevent that expansion by compressing it (negative stress). Hence, the resulting stresses from a thermal strain, when they exist, have opposite sign.